# Using .htaccess to rewrite a domain to another domain with the original domains name as a subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Assuming I have a range of domains with A records pointing to the same IP address:

- mainsite.com
- domain1.com
- domain2.org
- domain3.io
- ...many more

Is it possible to use .htaccess to rewrite the domains that are NOT mainsite.com to be

```
mainsite.com/domain/other-domain-name.tld/
```

For example:
Visiting

```
mainsite.com/pages/blog
```

will arrive at the blog without being affected.

Visiting

```
some-other-domain.com
```

or

```
some-other-domain.com/some/folder/page.html
```

will be redirected to

```
mainsite.com/domain/some-other-domain.com/
```

Many thanks =)

Comment: Yes!: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Hi @Croises. Yes I have read the page already. I'm new to using .htaccess and it's taken me a few hours just to stop my mod_rewrite spiralling into an infinite loop. Could you help with the actual syntax at all please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some alterations to @anubhava's code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mainsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mainsite.com/domain/%{HTTP_HOST} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mainsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mainsite.com/domain%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. When I try this I do see redirects happening, but %{REQUEST_URI} seems to be coming back as `/`
so http://www.wrongdomain.com -> http://rightdomain.com//

Comment: ok I updated my rule to include `/domain` also. You may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.